# Accordion takes 2 clicks to initiate + icon rotation

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion, rotatetransform

I pieced together some code I found for a FAQ accordion on my site.
I am not sure how to make the title expand with 1 click, as it currently takes 2.
I would also like the icon to rotate upon expanding/collapsing.
It is currently only rotating on/off hover.
I am including a short example of what I currently have.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```js
  $('.js-question').on('click', function(e) {
    var $answer = $(this).next(),
      actveClass = 'active',
      isActive = $answer.hasClass(actveClass);
    $('.answer').slideUp().addClass(actveClass);
    if (isActive) {
      $answer.toggleClass(actveClass);
      $answer.slideToggle();
    }
  });
```

```css
.faqContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.question {
    font-family: Arial MT Pro!important;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
    
.answer {
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    margin: 10px 0 15px
}
    
.answer a{
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #333!important;
}
    
.answer:hover a{
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ababab!important;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s
}

.faqContainer hr {
    opacity: 0;
}

.bracket-button .outer {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: 'Arial MT Pro';
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
    
.bracket-button .inner {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1547/5153/t/167/assets/cross.svg?v=1631342608) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215,  0.61,  0.355,  1);
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
    
.bracket-button:hover .inner {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215,  0.61,  0.355,  1);
    padding: 0px;
}
    
.bracket-button.active .inner {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1547/5153/t/167/assets/cross.svg?v=1631342608) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: 0px;
}
    
.bracket-button.active:hover .inner {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqContainer">
<p class="question js-question bracket-button">LOGISTICS<span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span></p>
<div class="answer">Pre-order items will ship roughly 2-3 weeks from the end date specified in the product description.<br />This can sometimes take longer due to print shop schedules/holidays.<br />All in stock orders are shipped within 48 hours of purchase, usually less.<br />Orders placed Friday evenings will typically ship the following Monday.<br />Most domestic orders are delivered within a week.<br />Please allow additional time in transit for delivery.<br /> If your order contains pre-order and in stock items,<br />your order will ship when all items are on-hand.<br />Please place separate orders if you need the in stock item(s) sooner.</div>
<hr />
<p class="question js-question bracket-button">DISCOUNTS<span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span></p>
<div class="answer">Domestic orders $75+ receive free shipping. <br /> Canada orders $125+ receive free shipping. <br /> Everywhere else orders $150+ receive free shipping.</div>
<hr />
<p class="question js-question bracket-button">CANCELLATIONS<span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span></p>
<div class="answer">If you canceled an order, expect to see the funds back in your account<br />within 2-3 business days, depending on your bank.</div>
<hr />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending contradicting orders to your function. Here `$('.answer').slideUp().addClass(actveClass);` you're sliding up all of the answers and adding the active class to all of them (I believe you wanted to remove it).

Then, you ask if the target answer has the active class (the answer is obviously yes, no matter what, because you have added it to all of the elements right before).

This conditional `if (isActive) {`, even if your previous code was correct, would be completely unnecessary. What you can do remove the active class from all of answers except the target one, and then toggle the clicked answer only, which you have already targeted here `$answer = $(this).next()`.

So the working code would be:

```js
$('.js-question').on('click', function(e) {
    var $answer = $(this).next(),
      actveClass = 'active';    
    $('.answer').not($answer).slideUp().removeClass(actveClass); /* remove instead of add and apply in every answer except the clicked one*/
    /* remove unnecessary conditional */  
      $answer.toggleClass(actveClass);
      $answer.slideToggle();
  });
```

```css
.faqContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.question {
    font-family: Arial MT Pro!important;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
    
.answer {
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    margin: 10px 0 15px
}
    
.answer a{
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #333!important;
}
    
.answer:hover a{
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ababab!important;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s
}

.faqContainer hr {
    opacity: 0;
}

.bracket-button .outer {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: 'Arial MT Pro';
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
    
.bracket-button .inner {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1547/5153/t/167/assets/cross.svg?v=1631342608) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215,  0.61,  0.355,  1);
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
    
.bracket-button:hover .inner {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215,  0.61,  0.355,  1);
    padding: 0px;
}
    
.bracket-button.active .inner {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1547/5153/t/167/assets/cross.svg?v=1631342608) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: 0px;
}
    
.bracket-button.active:hover .inner {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqContainer">
<p class="question js-question bracket-button">LOGISTICS<span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span></p>
<div class="answer">Pre-order items will ship roughly 2-3 weeks from the end date specified in the product description.<br />This can sometimes take longer due to print shop schedules/holidays.<br />All in stock orders are shipped within 48 hours of purchase, usually less.<br />Orders placed Friday evenings will typically ship the following Monday.<br />Most domestic orders are delivered within a week.<br />Please allow additional time in transit for delivery.<br /> If your order contains pre-order and in stock items,<br />your order will ship when all items are on-hand.<br />Please place separate orders if you need the in stock item(s) sooner.</div>
<hr />
<p class="question js-question bracket-button">DISCOUNTS<span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span></p>
<div class="answer">Domestic orders $75+ receive free shipping. <br /> Canada orders $125+ receive free shipping. <br /> Everywhere else orders $150+ receive free shipping.</div>
<hr />
<p class="question js-question bracket-button">CANCELLATIONS<span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span></p>
<div class="answer">If you canceled an order, expect to see the funds back in your account<br />within 2-3 business days, depending on your bank.</div>
<hr />
</div>
```

**Update to have the icon working properly**

Same method as for the `.answer`. You remove the active class from all the buttons except the clicked one, and then toggle the clicked button class.

```js
$('.js-question').on('click', function(e) {
  var $answer = $(this).next(),
    actveClass = 'active';
  $('.bracket-button').not($(this)).removeClass(actveClass);
  $('.answer').not($answer).slideUp().removeClass(actveClass);
  $(this).toggleClass(actveClass);
  $answer.toggleClass(actveClass);
  $answer.slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.faqContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.question {
    font-family: Arial MT Pro!important;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 300;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
    
.answer {
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    margin: 10px 0 15px
}
    
.answer a{
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #333!important;
}
    
.answer:hover a{
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ababab!important;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s
}

.faqContainer hr {
    opacity: 0;
}

.bracket-button .outer {
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: 'Arial MT Pro';
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
    
.bracket-button .inner {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1547/5153/t/167/assets/cross.svg?v=1631342608) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215,  0.61,  0.355,  1);
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
    
.bracket-button:hover .inner {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.215,  0.61,  0.355,  1);
    padding: 0px;
}
    
.bracket-button.active .inner {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1547/5153/t/167/assets/cross.svg?v=1631342608) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: 0px;
}
    
.bracket-button.active:hover .inner {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="faqContainer">
  <p class="question js-question bracket-button">LOGISTICS<span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
  </p>
  <div class="answer">Pre-order items will ship roughly 2-3 weeks from the end date specified in the product description.<br />This can sometimes take longer due to print shop schedules/holidays.<br />All in stock orders are shipped within 48 hours of purchase, usually less.<br
    />Orders placed Friday evenings will typically ship the following Monday.<br />Most domestic orders are delivered within a week.<br />Please allow additional time in transit for delivery.<br /> If your order contains pre-order and in stock items,<br
    />your order will ship when all items are on-hand.<br />Please place separate orders if you need the in stock item(s) sooner.</div>
  <hr />
  <p class="question js-question bracket-button">DISCOUNTS<span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
  </p>
  <div class="answer">Domestic orders $75+ receive free shipping. <br /> Canada orders $125+ receive free shipping. <br /> Everywhere else orders $150+ receive free shipping.</div>
  <hr />
  <p class="question js-question bracket-button">CANCELLATIONS<span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>
  </p>
  <div class="answer">If you canceled an order, expect to see the funds back in your account<br />within 2-3 business days, depending on your bank.</div>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response.

I actually want to be able to open and close each tab, as the original code demonstrates. Your solution fixes having to click the tab twice to activate it, but they are unable to be closed, as you pointed out.

In conjunction with the above, the icon to the right of the title would rotate as it opens/closes (and not just while hovering). I'm not sure what I'm missing with the CSS to achieve this part of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't undersand you. I have edited the fiddle to work as intended. All you have to do is apply the changes to all of the `.answers` except the clicked one: `$('.answer').not($answer).slideUp().removeClass(actveClass);`. The rest of the explanation still applies. ;)

Comment: Ok, so the problem with your icon is that you're not adding the active class to the button, you're adding it to the answer, so `.bracket-button.active` will not work with the jQuery function as it is right now. You'll need to toggle the button class too to properly work with your CSS. Let me have a look at it. ;)

Comment: Ok, I've added a new fiddle with the button class toggle too. I don't know if that's the effect you wanted to achieve, but now the jquery is ready so that you can adjust it through CSS.